# Can i build a very powerful central system and connect to multiple monitors to play different games at once

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

Basically I want to setup a gaming hub and instead of having separate systems I wanted to do something different and setup a central computer connected to multiple monitors and multiple in/out devices. Is this possible ? Any suggestions on what i might need to do to achieve this.

Comment: While possible in theory, I don't think you will enjoy the result for gaming - first of all, aside from the Wii, I don't know of any systems that allow for multiple direct independent inputs, which leaves you at having a server with many clients that remote in - this would work well for many situations, but not so much for gaming, where the graphics are high, and latency is critical. Multiple sessions also typically require a server-OS, which can be quite costly. Finally, hardware costs do not scale well at the high-end, it's more efficient to have separate systems than a single high-end one.

Comment: Can you?  I suppose its possible if you were to use a Server edition of Windows.  But you would spend more money building hardware and OS licensing to have the capability to run several games then it would cost to have multiple system in order to run several games.  Most software is designed to use most system resources, this means, you would still be limited to a single foreground application at a time.

Comment: Well then i suppose i need a supercomputer to achieve this. I thought i could save some money by using a single hardware but there is definitely more to this than i expected it to be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to do this, effectively making the computer into a game server.

However, the type of games that would support this will be limited. Web-browser based games for example should work fine as you could load each one into a separate browser window. Though you would certainly have to tweak any existing game so that it could differentiate between different controllers.

First person shooters on the other hand will take all the resources they can get.

So choose a type of game that isn't too heavy on resources and that can be tweaked, look for JavaScript or HTML5 based games for a slightly easier start. Text-based adventure games might work well.

Then decide how you will control the different windows. You might need to create a custom set of inputs or choose games easily controlled with a few keys on the keyboard so that you can change the keys for each game across the keyboard.

As others have said, you could also run controls from remote connections but Windows desktop limits the number of inbound network connections that can be made. Games with minimal controls (especially scripted ones as I've mentioned) may well be remotely controllable using simple scripts.